# How to return a View in a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
Class Student   {
  String Name {get; set}

  //Extended property of the student
  School Shooling {get; set;}   
}


public StudentControlelr ()
{

 public SchoolInfo (int? ID)
{
      Student s = StudentRepository.GetStudentByID(id)
      Return View ("Schooling/Index", s.Schooling);
}

}

for some reason i have to make this view as a shared view 
// Views/Shared/schooling.ascx
Return View ("Schooling", s.Schooling);
```

This works but why not if its in a different view folder it won't work? Am I missing some thing here?

Please note that ASP.net novice.

Kind Regards
Vinay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect to the action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
```

The only issue here is that you cannot pass a model, but there are a couple ways to get around this:

**Pass parameter and get the model upon load**

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = 1});
```

**Pass the model using TempData**

```
TempData["MyModel"] = s.Schooling;
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work but a better solution would be to redirect to a different action:

```
return View ("~/Views/Schooling/Index.aspx", s.Schooling);
```

Note: You will need to change .aspx to your views extension if you are not using ASPX Views.